# ItemNews on hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Create component ItemNews on hooks with props: length (the symbols quantity shown as default), content (the news text) and img (pic url).
Basically, the item should show only length-symbols quantity from content. There should also be a button 'Open'that shows the whole item text if clicked and vise versa(button 'hide' shows default text).

That's just for training, but I can't get it. I wrote something and it even works somehow...but your opinion could be truly prescious...

```
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";
 
function App() {
  const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);
  const image = <img src={"http:placekitten.com/300/"} alt={"kitten"}></img>;
  const extraContent = (
    <div>
      <p className="extra-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui,
        consectetur neque ab porro quasi culpa nulla rerum quis minus
        voluptatibus sed hic ad quo sint, libero commodi officia aliquam!
        Maxime.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
  const buttonName = readMore ? "Read Less << " : "Read More >> ";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <image>{image}</image>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setReadMore(!readMore);
        }}
      >
        <h2>{buttonName}</h2>
      </button>
      {readMore && extraContent}
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the question here? Is there an issue with the code? If the code is correct and working then perhaps it'd be better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I'm not sure that it is correct ...and I have no idea how to make item -length here...Thank you for this link. I'll try to check there too)

Comment: Looks like I managed...

Comment: What item are you referring to? What length?

Answer (score 0):

```
`
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";

const ItemNews = ({ text, maxLenght, imgSrc }) => {
  const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);
  const Image = <img src={imgSrc} alt={"kitten"}></img>;
  const handleReadMore = () => setReadMore(!readMore);

  if (maxLenght >= text.length) {
    return (
      <div>
        <image>{Image}</image>
        <div>{text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const content = readMore ? text : text.substr(0, maxLenght) + "...";
  const buttonName = readMore ? "Read Less   " : "Read More   ";

  return (
    <div>
      <image>{Image}</image>
      <div>{content}</div>
      <button onClick={handleReadMore}>
        <h2>{buttonName}</h2>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const text = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui,
  consectetur neque ab porro quasi culpa nulla rerum quis minus
  voluptatibus sed hic ad quo sint, libero commodi officia aliquam!
  Maxime.`;
  const imgSrc = "http:placekitten.com/150/";

  return <ItemNews imgSrc={imgSrc} text={text} maxLenght={50} />;
}

export default App;
`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).